# How to set a timer to an ActionListener

Tags: java, timer

I have created a slot machine game. In my slot machine game I have a button that will generate three random images when it is pressed. I want this button to generate three random images 5 seconds after it is pressed. Here is my code for the button and its action listener.

```
   b1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        randomPictureGenerator(evt);
        repaint();    
      }

    });

private void randomPictureGenerator(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    this.run(); 
    }
  public void run() {
    pictures = new ArrayList<>();
    pictures.add(new File("question.png"));
    pictures.add(new File("banana.png"));
    pictures.add(new File("chocolate.png"));
    pictures.add(new File("icecream.png"));
    pictures.add(new File("bell.png"));
    pictures.add(new File("apple.png"));
    pictures.add(new File("money.png"));
    pictures.add(new File("number-7.png"));
    pictures.add(new File("necklace.png"));
    pictures.add(new File("gloves.png"));
    int number = rand.nextInt((pictures.size() -1/*Max*/ - 0/*min*/) + 1) + 0/*Min*/;
    this.label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(pictures.get(number).getAbsolutePath()));
    int number2 = rand2.nextInt((pictures.size() -1/*Max*/ - 0/*min*/) + 1) + 0/*Min*/;
    this.label2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(pictures.get(number2).getAbsolutePath()));
    int number3 = rand3.nextInt((pictures.size() -1/*Max*/ - 0/*min*/) + 1) + 0/*Min*/;
    this.label3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(pictures.get(number3).getAbsolutePath()));
}
```

Comment: Please add what you've tried already.

Comment: Consider using a `Timer` - see comment in answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where Threads come into play! you have a lot of reading to do from compiler errors through exception handling, threading and thread interruptions. But this can do what you want to do by putting this code in the run() method.

```
try {
Thread.sleep(5000);                 //5000 milliseconds is five seconds.
} catch(InterruptedException ex) {
 Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your solution worked! I will try to read more on exception handling!

Comment: Consider using a `Timer` rather than a Thread - Swing is not thread-safe - if you are changing the UI (eg `setIcon`) it should be done on the EDT: a `Timer` guarantees its action occurs on the EDT, whereas a Thread needs explicit dispatching via `SwingUtilities`